# Defining all points on a hemisphere that intersect with a tilted plane.

Tags: geometry, python

I have a hemisphere centered on the origin of radius R. I also have a plane which runs through the origin, is parallel to the y-axis, and is tilted at an angle $\alpha$ with respect to the z-axis.

An image is below (the dotted line represents the plane):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na4n9.jpg)

From the setup we can write:
$$\hat{n} = -\cos(\alpha)\hat{x} + \sin(\alpha)\hat{z}$$
which means the equation of the plane is:
$$0=-\cos(\alpha)x + \sin(\alpha)z$$
The equation of the sphere is:
$$R^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2$$
Setting these equations equal, converting to spherical coordinates, and solving for $\theta(\phi,\alpha)$, gives:

$$\theta(\phi,\alpha) = \arcsin[(\cos^2(\phi)\csc^2(\alpha) +\sin^2(\phi))^{-1/2}]$$

I made a polar plot of this in python by parameterizing this equation for $\phi = [0,180]$. I set values on one side of the intersection to 1 and the other side to zero.

I expected to see a crescent shape across the polar plot, however when values approach the minimum polar angle, I notice a cusp that I don't believe should be there:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQTpb.png)

The above image shows the plane tilted at around 20 degrees.

I'm not sure where the error lies, but would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: The intersection is an arc of a circle and its projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane is an arc of an ellipse, so you’re right that there shouldn’t be a cusp.

Comment: Thanks. At this point I'm trying to determine if the issue is in my math, or my code.

Answer (score 1):

As you’ve already worked out, an equation of the plane is $x\cos\alpha=z\sin\alpha$. Substituting spherical coordinates into this equation results in $\rho\cos\phi\sin\theta\cos\alpha = \rho\cos\theta\sin\alpha$, or $$\cos\phi\tan\theta = \tan\alpha. \tag1$$ Now, the polar coordinates of the orthogonal projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane of the point with Cartesian coordinates $(\rho\cos\phi\sin\theta,\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta,\rho\cos\theta)$ are $$(\rho\sin\theta,\phi).\tag2$$ From equation (1) we have $$\sin\theta = {\tan\theta \over \sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}} = {\tan\alpha\sec\phi \over \sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha\sec^2\phi}} = {1\over\sqrt{1+\cot^2\alpha\cos^2\phi}}\tag3$$ and $\rho=R$, therefore the polar equation of the projected curve is $$r(\phi) = {R \over \sqrt{1+\cot^2\alpha\cos^2\phi}}. \tag 4$$ The expression for $\sin\theta$ in (3) is not equal to the one that you derived, but if you replace the expression inside the $\arcsin$ in yours with its reciprocal they are equal, so it looks like you got a fraction flipped somewhere along the way.

It’s also possible to find a Cartesian equation of the projected curve fairly directly: the plane-sphere intersection is a circle, so its projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane is an axis-aligned ellipse centered at the origin. The major axis lies along the $y$-axis and the semiaxis length is simply $R$. The semiminor axis length is foreshortened to $R\sin\alpha$, so a Cartesian equation of the ellipse is $${x^2\over R^2\sin^2\alpha}+{y^2\over R^2}=1. \tag 5$$ If you plug these semiaxis lengths into the generic [polar equation of an ellipse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), you’ll end up with something equivalent to equation (4). Another relatively painless approach to finding an equation of the curve is to parameterize the circle as $(R\cos t)(\sin\alpha,0,\cos\alpha)+(R\sin t)(0,1,0).$ Projecting this onto the $x$-$y$ plane is a simple matter of dropping the $z$-coordinate to get $(R\sin\alpha\cos t,R\sin t)$. Eliminating $t$ produces equation (5) again. Note, though, that $t$ in this parameterization doesn’t represent the polar angle.